# How to streamingly to read text file with Perl

Tags: perl

it can display text in file, however, after i add new text in gedit, it do not show the updated one.

```
sub start_thread {
my @args = @_;
print('Thread started: ', @args, "\n");
open(my $myhandle,'<',@args) or die "unable to open file";  # typical open call
for (;;) {
    while (<$myhandle>) {
    chomp;
    print $_."\n";
    }
    sleep 1;
    seek FH, 0, 1;      # this clears the eof flag on FH
}
}
```

**update video**
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4hnKBXrOBqRWEdjTDFIbHJselk/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4hnKBXrOBqRcEFhU3k4dUN4cXc/edit?usp=sharing

how to print $curpos for updated data

```
for (;;) {
        for ($curpos = tell($myhandle); $_ = <$myhandle>;
            $curpos = tell($myhandle)) {
             # search for some stuff and put it into files
         print $curpos."\n";
        }
        sleep(1);
        seek(FILE, $curpos, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate File::Tail? https://metacpan.org/module/File::Tail

Comment: Works for me (assuming you correct FH to $myhandle) as long as you just extend the file.

Comment: i updated FH to myhandle still not work

Comment: Why `chomp` if you are going to be printing `$_."\n"` in the next line?

Comment: Is it possible that gedit renamed the original file to file.bak and added your extra text to an entirely new copy of the file ?  If so, your perl script might be looking at the backup copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said - it works for me. Changes to your script are minimal - just minimal cleanup.

Script: test_tail.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub tail_file {
    my $filename = shift;
    open(my $myhandle,'<',$filename) or die "unable to open file";  # typical open call
    for (;;) {
        print "About to read file...\n";
        while (<$myhandle>) {
            chomp;
            print $_."\n";
        }
        sleep 1;
        seek $myhandle, 0, 1;      # this clears the eof flag on FH
    }
}

tail_file('/tmp/test_file.txt');
```

Then:

```
echo -e "aaa\nbbb\nccc\n" > /tmp/test_file.txt
# wait a bit
echo -e "ddd\neee\n" >> /tmp/test_file.txt
```

Meanwhile (in a different terminal);

```
$ perl /tmp/test_tail.pl 
About to read file...
aaa
bbb
ccc

About to read file...
About to read file...
About to read file...
ddd
eee
```

Comment: already keep simple, still have error https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4hnKBXrOBqRcEFhU3k4dUN4cXc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: i run your script, it can not display too

Comment: If my script doesn't work then it's either something in your filesystem, perl-version or similar. You've not said what your version does though. Oh - why are you posting blurred video of you doing something in a text-editor and MySQL Workbench? If there's supposed to be something useful in there, post the text to this website.

Comment: i updated my question after search another method, how to print the updated position text?

Comment: i just install ubuntu 12 in ubuntu web site today, i guess it is using updated stable version, use whole screen, it will not blur

Comment: When I watch TV, it's usually a comedy, not some-one typing. And you've just changed the question without resolving the first one. Ho hum.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
seek $myhandle, 0, 1;      # this clears the eof flag on FH
```

Can you try something like this:

```
my $pos = tell $myhandle;
seek $myhandle, $pos, 0;      # reset the file handle in an alternate way
```

Answer (score 0):

The file system is trying to give you a consistent view of the file you are reading.  To see the changes, you would need to reopen the file.

To see an example of this, try the following:

1.Create a file that has 100 lines of text in it, a man page, for instance:

```
man tail > foo
```

2.Print the file slowly:

```
cat foo | perl -ne 'print; sleep 1;'
```

3.While that is going on, in another shell or editor, try editing the file by deleting most lines

Result:  The file will continue to print slowly, as if you never edited it.  Only when you try to print it again, will you see the changes.

Comment: i need to run perl instead of bash

Comment: This is using perl.  The perl script is 'print; sleep 1', and it sees only the unchanged version of the file.

Comment: You should consider trying File::Tail

Answer (score 0):

The following would also work:

```
my $TAIL = '/usr/bin/tail -f';  # Adjust accordingly
open my $fh, "$TAIL |"
    or die "Unable to run $TAIL : $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    # do something
}
```